# Create Element with javascript then animate it with css

Tags: javascript, html, css, transition, createelement

Is it possible to create a new element with javascript and add it to body, then automatically animate it with css? This is my test page

```
<body>

<script>
function menuMain(){
    Title = document.createElement("div");
    Title.style.left = "750px";
    Title.style.webkitTransition = "4s";
    Title.style.fontSize = "30px";
    Title.style.position = "fixed";
    Title.style.color = "red";
    Title.id = "titleid";
    Title.innerHTML = "Menu Title";
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(Title);
    Title.style.left = "200px";
}

menuMain();
</script>

</body>
```

But it just automatically places the object at `left:200px`, instead of animating it from 750px to 200px.
I know `Title.style.webkitTransition = "4s"` works because when I inspect element it's there in the element's style

I also tried replacing

```
Title.style.left = "200px";
```

with

```
document.getElementById("titleid").style.left = "200px";
```

but it just does the same thing.

I know when I create the element manually, then change left with javascript it animated from `left:750px` to `left:200px`

```
<body>
<div id="titleid" style="-webkit-transition:4s;position:absolute;color:red;font-size:30px;left:750px;">Menu Title</div>
<script>
function menuMain(){
    document.getElementById("titleid").style.left = "200px";
}

menuMain();
</script>

</body>
```

but this is not what I want to do. So is it possibly somehow?

Comment: I think the problem is the browser reads the left:200px; after the left:700px; so it never knows to transition from one point to another. It just puts it at 200px. It might be working when you do it manually because it actually has to sets of numbers to work with and the HTML is rendered before the js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you just want a transition, take a look at jQuery animation: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

It will make something like this trivial.

Comment: Will do. But is it possible to do it in traditional javascript that isn't too complicated? if not I'll have to settle for jquery

Comment: Well I tried jquery and it works like a charm. :) Thank you. I've been hesitant about using jquery but it seems I may use it more in the future ;P